# How do i create a constraint for my button, so it wont mess up the size of it

Tags: ios, xcode, button, constraints, sizing

i have a button i want to have the same distance from screen edge on all devices, i put a constraint on right which works nicely but on bottom  it messed up the size of my button. I tried making it bigger with the same constraint but it gives me warnings saying the size will be different at run time.

[before i put the bottom (y) constraint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgmNt.jpg)

[after the y constraint is added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxOkQ.jpg)

[with two constrains and after i stretch out resulting in misplaced view warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lx0vQ.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you also have a constraint from the leading side of the button to the left side of the screen with a constant of 0. Then, add a horizontal constraint.